# Alternate way of comparing two columns in a table performance wise in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have below query and getting correct result. But I want to know which query is good performance/code standard wise from the below queries.

```
DECLARE @TBL AS TABLE (Column1 INT NULL ,Column2 INT NULL)
INSERT INTO @TBL(Column1,Column2)
VALUES(25,25)
     ,(21,NULL)
```

Query1:

```
SELECT * FROM @TBL 
WHERE COALESCE(Column1,'') <> COALESCE(Column2,'')
 OR(Column1 IS NULL AND Column2 IS NOT NULL)
```

Query2:

```
SELECT * FROM @TBL 
WHERE ISNULL(NULLIF(Column1, Column2), NULLIF(Column2, Column1)) IS NOT NULL
 OR(Column1 IS NULL AND Column2 IS NOT NULL)
```

Query3:

```
SELECT * FROM @TBL WHERE ISNULL(Column1,'') ! = ISNULL(Column2,'')
 OR(Column1 IS NULL AND Column2 IS NOT NULL)
```

The result should be

```
Column1      Colum2
   21         Null
```

Can anyone please suggest for the above.

Comment: None of them, this one is probably better `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Column1 INTERSECT SELECT Column2)`. Although it's unclear what you want here, it looks like your syntax would make `''` equal to `NULL`, was that the intention?

Comment: Doing this comparison between two columns at runtime is going to require a full scan of both columns in all rows however you write it. To optimise performance of this `SELECT` you could put the expression testing for equality in a computed column and index that if this check is happening often enough to warrant that

Comment: @SasiBhushanaRao . . . Your table is really too small to be worried about performance considerations.  All the queries should be so fast that it will be hard to measure the differences unless you run them thousands of times in a timing comparison.

Comment: I would imagine this was intended to be a **Minimal**, Reproducible Example

Comment: @MartinSmith If you have a look at the dupe and Paul White's article linked there, you will see that that syntax does *not* require a full scan and will use an index seek. Incidentally, the `...<>...OR...IS NULL OR...IS NULL` also compiles down to an index seek.

Comment: @Charlieface [I'm well aware of that article](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a73226%20undocumented%20query%20plans%20Equality%20Comparisons%20) - but not applicable here. What you have missed is that here the values being compared are in the same row. Not, as in the article, where an outer reference from one table is being used to seek into another table. Here You don't know the value of `column2` and `column1` until you visit the row so there is nothing to seek into to find the row. For similar reasons `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Col1=Col2` can't use an index seek either

Comment: and for that reason this question is not a dupe

Comment: Given that there are no keys nor indexes on `@Tbl` then either they will all be near-equally bad or (more likely) `@Tbl` is too small to matter.  In both cases it's best to just do it the simplest and most straightforward way.

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully sure what you like to achieve and therefore assumed the following question for my answer:

`Return every row where Column1 is not equal to Column2 independently whether they are null or not.`

This question I would solve like this, avoiding any functions which I assume must be slower.

```
SELECT * FROM @TBL 
WHERE (Column1 <> Column2) OR 
      ((Column1 IS NULL) AND (Column2 IS NOT NULL)) OR 
      ((Column2 IS NULL) AND (Column1 IS NOT NULL));
```

The final answer you find out through measuring in your environment.

Comment: This result is good for me. But my doubt is how the below query is different from the query you suggested
SELECT * FROM @TBL 
WHERE COALESCE(Column1,'') <> COALESCE(Column2,'')
 OR(Column1 IS NULL AND Column2 IS NOT NULL)
I mean performance or standard wise which is good
could you please suggest

Comment: In your queries you are converting each value from an `INT` into a `VARCHAR` that is really bad performance-wise. The conversion costs, and the comparison is also much slower. Something like `ISNULL(Column1, -1) <> ISNULL(Column2, -1)` you could use as it keeps `INT` values but it assumes that `Column1` and `Column2` never contain negative values.